# MongoDB update/insert whole collection (array)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got collection of `items`,

```
[
    {
        itemId: 1249,
        someField: 'abc'
    },
    {
        itemId: 1479,
        anotherField: 'bcc'
    }
    ,
    // etc
]
```

I recieve another portion of data. Some of the items could already be there, some not,

```
[
    {
        itemId: 6534,
        someField: 'trw'
    },
    // already stored in collection..
    {
        itemId: 1249,
        someField: 'abc'
    }
]
```

I'm looking for the way of bulk insert of this data with `upsert` strategy (means, if item with such itemId is already there - update, otherwise insert).

Is that possible to do with only one query, of I need to go throught collection manually and upsert each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, probably not the most effecent method, but it works

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/devbed", {native_parser:true}, function(err, db) {
    db.collection(project.name).findOne({"revision":project.tmprev}, function(err,item){
                        if(item){
                          db.collection(project.name).update({JSON},{w:1},function(err, object) {
                              if (err) {console.warn(err.message);}
                              else {console.log("succesfully saved");
                              db.close();}
                          });
                        }
                        else{
                            db.collection(project.name).insert({JSON}]},{w:1},function(err, object) {
                            if (err) {console.warn(err.message);}
                            else {console.log("succesfully saved");
                            db.close();}
                            });
                        }

                    });
});
```

Wraping this in a function should work